# add and shift in verilog

Tags: algorithm, verilog, multiplication

Here's my verilog code about add and shift multiplying
when I compile and Initialze and adding the inputs and outputs to get waveforms and simulating them, I dont see any results, everything is z... what is the problem?

```
module multi(a, b, ans);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    output reg [15:0] ans;
    reg [15:0] aa;
    reg [15:0] bb;  
    reg [15:0] tmp=0;
    reg flag = 1'b1;

    always @( a, b)
        begin       
            aa = a;
            bb = b;
            while ( flag == 1'b1 )
            begin
            if( bb[0] == 1'b1 )
                tmp = tmp + aa; 
            aa = aa << 1;
            bb = bb >> 1;
            if ( bb==0 )
                flag = 1'b0;
            end
            ans = tmp;
        end  

endmodule
```

Comment: What is your toplevel testbench?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that look strange with this code.

First is that you have no clock input, but are attempting to do everything with combinatorial logic.

Second is that setting flag to 1 in the reg statement will mean that your module is only capable of doing a single multiplication.  By the way, it is more normal (especially for ASIC design) to use a reset signal than use this initialisation in a reg line.

Third is that a 4 bit number times a 4 bit number will result in an 8bit answer, not 16bit.

In any case, unless you are working at very high speeds you should be able to perform a multiply in a single cycle.

Here are a couple of ways of writing this code more naturally:

### Combinatorial Style

```
module multi(a, b, ans);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    output reg [7:0] ans;

    always @(*)
        begin 
            ans = a * b;      
        end  
endmodule
```

### Clocked style

```
module multi(clk, a, b, ans);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    output reg [7:0] ans;

    always @(posedge clk)
        begin 
            ans <= a * b;      
        end  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is 4 bits wide and your assigning to a 16 bit variable, the top 12 bits are unassigned ie `x`.

```
input [3:0] a;
reg [15:0] aa;
//...
aa = a;
```

To assign all bits of `aa` try some thing like:

```
aa = {12'b0, a}; 
//{} is bit concatenation
```

Or to sign extend a to 16 bits, repeat the MSB 12 times using `{width{value}}` replication:

```
aa = {{12{a[3]}}, a};
```